# Network Endpoint Groups on GKE using shared VPC

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Is it possible to use Network Endpoint Groups (NEGs) on GKE with shared VPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hkanjih,

For your case, you can to use the Zonal network endpoint groups. Accordingly to Google documentation the primary use case for this configuration is deploying containers on your VMs so that you can run services in the containers. You can also distribute traffic in a granular fashion to applications running on the VMs. More information is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/zonal-neg-concepts).

The gce ingress controller is the ideal way to manage the NEGs. If you annotate the service with " cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}' ", the controller will automatically generate the NEGs when an ingress is generated and connected to the service. Details about how to implement it, can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing).

For specific use cases, you can also use Stand Alone NEGs. Check for more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg).

Comment: I'm not able to find any specifics in Google's documentation on how to create the NEG in a _shared VPC_, would you happen to have specifics on that?