# GCP, Nginx-Ingress: Network Endpoint Groups(NEG) not getting created for shared network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I am working on GCP with Nginx Ingress to create Network Endpoint Groups for a shared network. Unfortunately, it's not working for me.
I also tried the suggestions mentioned here: [Network Endpoint Groups on GKE using shared VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601735/network-endpoint-groups-on-gke-using-shared-vpc)

My nginx ingress code:

```
    service:
      annotations:
        cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {
          "80":{"name": "neg-http-ingress-v2"},
          "443":{"name":"neg-https-ingress-v2"}
        }}'
        cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
      loadBalancerIP: 10.68.37.123
```

There are no NEG's getting created. Is there any permission required or any extra steps to follow.

What am I missing?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Did you get any errors, check in logs for any errors which will help in debugging your issue, can you edit adding more details and error.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde: Unfortunately not, I checked service-accounts, GCP logs, cluster logs. Also added them manually before nginx-ingress installation as a trial to see if the ingress will then bound to it.

Comment: If you are using an Internal L7 (HTTP(S)) Load Balancer and according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal#firewall_rules:~:text=For%20regional%20internet,to%20egress.) for this type of load balancer, an additional ingress firewall rule is required to allow incoming traffic from the proxy-only subnet as part of the requirements for this scenario to work.

Comment: @SaiChandraGaddeI just confirmed, that we have a Proxy-subnet and it's FW rule as well. Please note, we have an existing cluster in the same project, which is part of peered network and we are moving to shared network. The loadbalancer, fw-rules are all there, but when we are adding a new cluster with shared network and installing nginx-ingress, the NEG's are not populating. We have NEG's for the older cluster, also tried different names.